# How long does it take for GA to update event labels?

Tags: google-analytics

On my site, I send GA some event data when a widget falls into a users' viewport.  Earlier today (about 7 hours ago), I changed the labels of those events.  I have kept the category the same.

When I navigate to "Behavior -> Top Events" panel on the GA dashboard, I don't see the new labels.  However, in the real time view, I see the new labels.

Should there be a discrepancy between the two panels?  Is there somewhere I can "hard refresh" the labels for GA?

Comment: Labels on your old data will never change, if that's what you mean? Once GA data is recorded it's immutable. Your new labels should start appearing in Top Events 3-4 hours after the first data with new labels is recorded, though it could take longer (but less than 24 hours).

Comment: Sorry, I worded the question wrong - yes, I mean I want to see the new labels.  The old labels shouldn't change.  Edited question for appropriate wording.